# Are there any academic sources on why people should use Linux?

Tags: linux

So, I have to write a persuasive speech for college.  I've decided on persuading people to switch to Linux.  The problem is, I should have five academic sources for my arguments.  Are there academic papers on why normal people should use Linux?  I know all the usual arguments, but I need to find sources to back me up.  I do have access to most academic databases via my college.  If there aren't really any good academic studies or other sources, I'll cite this question as a source and also use normal articles on the Internet.

I'm not asking for reasons why Linux is better, I'm looking for academic sources on why Linux is better.  I don't think that counts as opinion at all, it's pure facts and references.

Comment: I don't know about academic papers, but the free software foundation should have some good papers. You could try Richard Stallman's book [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=UJlNAgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=free+software+foundation&ots=bLxm7QqPcx&sig=-4ZJ7wRjq9zYWThznu4vkPn82QI#v=onepage&q=free%20software%20foundation&f=false). Otherwise I would just dig away on Google Scholar.

Comment: If you ask yourself "what and when is Linux", you will find resources for the key answers. Then you can construct an argument. If someone does not care for such ideas&technologies, and derives no immediate benefit, then why would he/she switch? There is most likely helpful insight in that question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this question is going to get answers that are opinionated, and so it really isn't a good fit for the SE sites.

There are 2 key aspects to using Linux over X.

1. The stack of software as well as the kernel are developed and licenses as open source.
2. The stack of software is highly customizable and configurable.

There are obviously other reasons but I'd try and frame your target a bit more. What's a "normal" user? People use what's easy to use and easily accessible. Linux by default is neither, to start. Using Linux takes sheer will to want to do it, so focusing on the reasons why someone would use Linux over X might be a more plausible way to communicate your argument.

I'd focus on the pluses of using an open sourced OS vs. a closed source one. Building off of this notion of "openness" as you walk users up through the stack of software from the Linux kernel up to the desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, etc.) to the web browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc.).

The key attribute that you get with Linux vs. Windows vs. OSX is **choice**. Is not having everything decided for you, out of the box. But with the ability to make your own software choices, comes the responsibility to choose, and to choose wisely!

#### Sourcing material

For sources to cite you'll probably find no better resource then searching through [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/), specifically looking for "[Linux Usability Studies](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=linux%20usability%20studies&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=8Rk6U8jjI8Pf2AWgl4GYBA&ved=0CDcQgQMwAA)."

#### References

- [Why Linux is Better](http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/)
- [The Cathedral and the Bazaar](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/)
- [The GNU Manifesto](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/manifesto.html)
- [Revolution OS](http://www.revolution-os.com/)
- [Open Source Initiative - OSI](http://opensource.org/)

Comment: I need _sources_, not reasons.  I have plenty of reasons.  I need sources to back the reasons up, as I said in my question.

Comment: @SkylarMT - patience, I'm adding some